# Is there a way to create a user control from a selection?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is to create a new ascx based on a selection?  To further clarify, I wonder if there's a way to select a block of HTML or ASP.NET code in a aspx or ascx file and turn that block into a separate user control. Does Resharper or Visual Studio have this capability?

Comment: Is it too hard to copy the code, create a new ascx file, and paste the code in?

Comment: Not really, but can be if you have to do it a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in VisualStudio 2013, but didn't see this option in VS 2005 or VS2010.
When you select the markup and RightClick, you have an option that says:

**Extract to UserControl**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Never saw this one. The problem with VS is there are so many options that the menus are becoming way overloaded.